# Php full name validation?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, preg-match

I need help with my php form validation. I want to validate the full name of a person. I have something like this:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/", $name)){
    echo '<h4 class="error">Name is not valid! It must not contain numbers   or special characters. <br> No letters or special characters allowed!</h4><a href="contact.php" class="button block">Go back and try again.</a>';
exit;
}
```

So far it works fine with reporting error if I write something like John* or Jo7hn or whatever. It works if I write Ivan-Ivan. The problem is if I write space in any way  it reports me the error. So how can I make it so that I can write full name with space without getting an error but still forbidd numbers and special characters? I feel like im missing something in that preg_match function but can't find it.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z/'/-\040]+$/", $name)){ ...
```

\040 is the space you want :)

[PHP Escape sequences](http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

I create a simple fiddle for you:

[the fiddle](http://www.regexr.com/3e7n9)

Comment: Escape character is backslash not forward slash. Why using octal `\040` instead of simple space?

Answer (score 2):

if($name==""){
        $text = "  **Error !**  field must not be empty ";
        return $text;
      }

```
    if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/", $name)){
    echo '<h4 class="error">Name is not valid! It must not contain numbers   or special characters </h4>.</a>';
    exit;
  }
```

Comment: Some additional explanations about this code only answer would probably be beneficial.

Comment: What question are you answering?